# Swift OS X Xcode Beta 3 - IBAction func has no access to global variable

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nsviewcontroller

I have 2 NSViewController Classes. On both is a NSButton. All works fine in the first VC. Pressing the button on the first VC opens the second VC.

First View Controller:

```
    import Cocoa

    class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var number: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        number = 4
        println("Number: \(number)") // WORKS
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("Number: \(number)") // WORKS
        let testViewController : TestViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("TestViewController") as TestViewController
        self.presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(testViewController as NSViewController)
    }
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
import Cocoa

class TestViewController: NSViewController {

    var number: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        number = 4
        println("Number: \(number)") // WORKS
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("Number: \(number)") // DOES NOT WORK: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }
}
```

Why has the second VC no access to the variable "number"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `self.number` just in case it is confusing the number variable with the one from the first view controller?